# Links that used to work now do not

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, broken-links

So I'm making a webpage in html5 for a school project, and some of my hyperlinks that were working before have become completely broken, so much so that even the a:hover attribute doesn't work.

Here is the exact code (comments included) for my About page, on which the hyperlinks on the left do work:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container {
 width:1024px;
 height:800px; 
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Background.png);
}

header{
 width:1024px;
 height:100px;
 text-align:left;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Top_Banner.png);s
 display:inline;
}

footer{
 width:1024px;
 height:80px;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-align:center;
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Bottom_Border.png);
}

#content{
 width:869px;
 height:620;
 padding-left:155px;
 padding-bottom:80px;
 position:absolute;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-align:center;
}

h2{
 color:#FFF;
}

h4{
 color:#FFF;
}

p{
 color:#FFF;
}

#left_bar{
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Sidebar.png);
 height:700px;
 width:155px;
 text-align:center;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFF;
}

a:hover{
 color:#000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="About.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>[Title Goes Here]</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <header>
                 <div style="line-height:5%;">
        <br>
     </div>
                <h2><a href="Title Goes Here.html" id="current">[Title Goes Here]:</a></h2>
                <h4>Adventures in Design</h4>
    </header>
                    <!-- CONTENT DIV HERE -->
                
       <div id="left_bar">
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#" id="current">ABOUT</a></h2>
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></h2>
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#">CONTACT</a></h2>
                            </div>


      <footer>
                        <br />
                        <p>Last Updated: 05-08-2017</p>
                        </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
 <!--<div style="border-left:1px solid #000;height:500px"></div>
  for vertical line -->
```

Here is the complete code for my main page, on which only the link leading back to the main page works:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container {
 width:1024px;
 height:800px; 
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Background.png);
}

header{
 width:1024px;
 height:100px;
 text-align:left;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Top_Banner.png);s
 display:inline;
}

footer{
 width:1024px;
 height:80px;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-align:center;
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Bottom_Border.png);
}

#content{
 width:869px;
 height:620;
 padding-left:155px;
 padding-bottom:80px;
 position:absolute;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-align:center;
}

h2{
 color:#FFF;
}

h4{
 color:#FFF;
}

p{
 color:#FFF;
}

#left_bar{
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Sidebar.png);
 height:700px;
 width:155px;
 text-align:center;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFF;
}

a:hover{
 color:#000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Front_Page.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>[Title Goes Here]</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 
    <header>
                 <div style="line-height:5%;">
        <br>
     </div>
                <h2><a href="Title Goes Here.html" id="current">[Title Goes Here]:</a></h2>
                <h4>Adventures in Design</h4>
    </header>
                         
                                                    <div id="content">
                                                    <h2> Hello and welcome to [Title Goes Here], <br  /> 
                                                    one adventure in design, from websites to photos and beyond!</h2>
                                                     <div style="line-height:217px;">
                 <br />
              </div>
                      <img src="Images/Front Page/Landscape.png" />
                      </div>
                
       <div id="left_bar">
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="About.html" id="current">ABOUT</a></h2>
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></h2>
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#">CONTACT</a></h2>
                            </div>
   
      <footer>
                        <br />
                        <p>Last Updated: 05-08-2017</p>
                        </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any answers to this would be much appreciated, as I have yet to find anything wrong. Thank you in advance for any advice you could throw my way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #content element is overlaid on top of your #left_bar element because of the `padding-left`. You can use `margin-left` instead.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container {
 width:1024px;
 height:800px; 
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Background.png);
}

header{
 width:1024px;
 height:100px;
 text-align:left;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Top_Banner.png);s
 display:inline;
}

footer{
 width:1024px;
 height:80px;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-align:center;
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Bottom_Border.png);
}

#content{
 width:869px;
 height:620;
 margin-left:155px;
 padding-bottom:80px;
 position:absolute;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 text-align:center;
}

h2{
 color:#FFF;
}

h4{
 color:#FFF;
}

p{
 color:#FFF;
}

#left_bar{
 background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Sidebar.png);
 height:700px;
 width:155px;
 text-align:center;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFF;
}

a:hover{
 color:#000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Front_Page.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>[Title Goes Here]</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 
    <header>
                 <div style="line-height:5%;">
        <br>
     </div>
                <h2><a href="Title Goes Here.html" id="current">[Title Goes Here]:</a></h2>
                <h4>Adventures in Design</h4>
    </header>
                         
                                                    <div id="content">
                                                    <h2> Hello and welcome to [Title Goes Here], <br  /> 
                                                    one adventure in design, from websites to photos and beyond!</h2>
                                                     <div style="line-height:217px;">
                 <br />
              </div>
                      <img src="Images/Front Page/Landscape.png" />
                      </div>
                
       <div id="left_bar">
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="About.html" id="current">ABOUT</a></h2>
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></h2>
                            <br />
                            <h2><a href="#">CONTACT</a></h2>
                            </div>
   
      <footer>
                        <br />
                        <p>Last Updated: 05-08-2017</p>
                        </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

First, you have an improperly formatted link href.

`href="Title Goes Here.html"`

As a rule, it is best practice to omit spaces in file names and replace them with dashes instead.

`href="title-goes-here.html"`

Second, when it comes to writing URL paths for things like images, if the goal is to grab files from a relative root directory, you should lead all URLs with a forward slash.

`background-image:url(/Images/All%20Pages/Background.png);`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I really should be doing that, but I find that it still works even with spaces, so that's what I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an extra "s" in the .header css section. Check the background-image line after the ";".

```
header{
    width:1024px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-image:url(Images/All%20Pages/Top_Banner.png);s
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: That didn't end up being the cause of the problem, but still thank you for pointing that out.